# EC2: how to download the private key file for a user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I'm only working with terminal in order to create a user on a linux machine (ec2).

When creating a new user and then generating an ssh key for this user
`ssh-keygen -f rsa` I do this

I then get a **rsa.pub**  file in the users home directory and I also have an .ssh directory with an **authorized_keys** file.

What I don't know now is how can I download the private key as a file to my computer in order to connect to the instance.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can use scp to transfer a file from the server.

```
scp -i <ec2-ssh-key> ec2-user@your-instance:/path/to/rsa <local_path>
```

It is also possible just to copy the content of a private key and paste into a local file.

e.g.

`cat ~/.ssh/rsa`

Comment: which one is the file I need to download? I don't have an ec2-key.pem yet on the machine for the new user

Comment: How do you connect to the EC2 instance? You use the same pem file to issue the scp command from your local host.

Comment: I use my very own pem file yes,  that I  got when creating the  account. However I'm looking to create a new connection file only for this instance (my pem file works for all instances) that I can share with let's say a thrid party developer somewhere to have access to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Following steps to setup passwordless authentication on EC2.**

1. Login to you EC2 machine as a root user.
2. Create a new user

   ```
   useradd -m <yourname> 
   sudo su <yourname>
   cd 
   mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

Append contents of file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on you local machine to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on EC2 machine.

```
chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

1. Make sure sshing is permitted by the machine. In file
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config, make sure that line containing
   "PasswordAuthentication yes" is uncommented. Restart sshd service if
   you make any change in this file:

   service sshd restart # On Centos

   service ssh restart # On Ubuntu
2. Your passwordless login should work now. Try following on your local
   machine:

> ssh -A
>   @ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com